# How to properly organize an API-app with Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, structure, code-structure

I have some related basic questions on properly organizing an API-app. Although its a general question it might be of interest that I'm using Laravel.

My structure is as follows:

- A rest api with endpoints pointing to different methods within Controller classes. The passed object is of type Request.
- The controller classes do all the input validation (through validate-methods), authorizations (through Gates) and fetch the respective models from database (based on an id from the Request). In case the models do not exists, it returns an error. Finally, the controller calls the respective method within my Service classes, passing the model object.
- The service classes now perform different actions on the model instance (e.g. updating the username), persist the update (using Eloquent) and finally return the updated model instance to the controller.
- The controller "wraps" the returned object into a json response and return it to the client (I just like returning the whole updated object instead of just returning success or the id).

My questions and problems:

1. Is the organization of my code ok?
2. As stated, validation errors etc. are thrown from my controllers. However, what if something goes wrong within my service (i.e. further down)? how can I tell my controller that something went wrong, so that it can return a 403 (for example) JSON response to the client? Example: my UserService tries to update the email address. However, there is already an entry with this email, so the Service needs to return an error back to the controller, which in turn returns a 403 json-encoded error message to the client.
3. As stated, all validation, authorization and so in is done in my controller. the controller methods are made especially for http requests and thus take a Request object as input and return json. What if I want to call these methods directly from within my app, for example from another controller? If I call the respective Service class directly, I cannot benefit from all the validations and checks that are done within the controller. However, if I call the controller, it expects a Request object as input and returns a Json http response, which I both do not want when calling from another controller, obviously. How should I do this?

I hope my problems are sufficiently clear!? Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer a couple of these things.

1. I think it looks ok for an API; just be sure to keep API logic separate from application logic. The way I do this is via routing; `/api/{version}/...` as an example.
2. Use `try { ... } catch { ... }` blocks to handle unforeseen errors (like SQL exceptions, etc) and return `response()->json([...], 403);` in those cases.
3. Use the `guzzle/http` (requires including it in your `composer.json` and running a `composer install` or `composer update`) package to send requests from routes/controllers within your application. You can simply access a route from your application that `GET` or `POST`s to an `/api/...` route; it will recognize it as a `Request` and has functions to handle returned `JSON` response. See http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/ for examples.

It's a bit of an open-ended question though; best to try building your API and addressing the specific issues that arise.

Comment: thank you very much, that is exactly I was hoping to get as an answer! I will try and come back in case any questions arise! thx!!!